# Elastic Cloud, Filebeat, and Key/Token Authentication

Tags: elasticsearch, token, filebeat, elastic-cloud

Is it possible configure filebeat to communicate with an Elastic Cloud instance **using token authentication**?

According [to the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-installation-configuration.html#set-connection), if I'm using a cloud instance I should configure `cloud.id` and `cloud.auth` in `filebeat.yml`

```
cloud.id: "..."
cloud.auth: "filebeat_setup:YOUR_PASSWORD"
```

The docs say that `cloud.auth` should be a username and password from my Elastic Cloud instance.  I'd like to use an api_key instead.  However, when I configure an [API key](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/beats-api-keys.html)

```
output.elasticsearch:
  # Authentication credentials - either API key or username/password.
  api_key: "key-id:key-value"
```

and attempt to test my connection,

```
$ sudo filebeat test output
elasticsearch: https://...:443...
  parse url... OK
  connection...
    parse host... OK
    dns lookup... OK
    addresses: 52.202.123.120, 18.214.74.184, 50.19.154.221
    dial up... OK
  TLS...
    security: server's certificate chain verification is enabled
    handshake... OK
    TLS version: TLSv1.2
    dial up... OK
  talk to server... ERROR 401 Unauthorized: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"missing authentication credentials for REST request [/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":["Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\"","Bearer realm=\"security\"","ApiKey"]}}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"missing authentication credentials for REST request [/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":["Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\"","Bearer realm=\"security\"","ApiKey"]}},"status":401}
```

It appears that `filebeat` doesn't acknowledge my API Key

```
"root_cause":[
    {
     "type":"security_exception",
     "reason":"missing authentication credentials for REST request [/]"
/* ... */
```

I've had success connecting to my cloud instance with the `@elastic/elasticsearch` javascript package using this token.

Before I continue to debug this probiem -- is it even *possible* to use token authentication to connection to Elasticsearch via `filebeat`?  Or does `filebeat` only support username/password authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question turned out to be: Yes, you can use an `api_key` with filebeat, even if you're using elastic cloud.

While the error message received during my config test

> missing authentication credentials for REST request

indicated the authentication was missing, the real problem was the key I had had previous success with had recently expired.  I presume filebeat tried the API key, was rejected, and then fell back to trying the user credentials.  When those credentials were missing, it gave the above error.